# microprofile-openapi-api 2.0 switches off hibernate-jpamodelgen

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-management, microprofile, hibernate-jpa

I have a java microservice-project with theese two dependencies defindes in my gradle.build file:

implementation(group: 'org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi', name: 'microprofile-openapi-api', version: '1.2')

annotationProcessor('org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-jpamodelgen:6.1.6.Final')

This works, meaning that i get my JPA metamodels created. But as soon as i bump microprofile-openapi-api to 2.0 or above, jpamodelgen no longer gets run (no errors, it just does not run). It is like clockwork, that going above 1.2 creates the problem.

Any ideas as to what is causing this behavior and what can be done ?

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out that openaoi-api 2.0 and forward has a bug. Content-types can’t be constants.

Taking the string values from these constants and applying them directly solves the problem.